# React Convert application md to pdf

Tags: reactjs

React file format conversion

The .md file selected in the input in the project should be converted into a .pdf file. Is there this project or similar projects? None of the methods I wrote worked, it returned a blank pdf file output

Answer (score 0):

I personally won't write this code for you, but others might !

I'm simply here to inform you a bit on how Stack Overflow works.

When you encounter a problem that isn't a compiler error, you first will want to ask a rubber duck (which means you read your code line by line and try to catch any errors in your logic).
Then if that doesn't work, go look up what you're trying to do on the internet, chances are, someone, at some point has tried something similar and their work will most likely help you in yours.
And if that still doesn't make it for you, THEN you ask on Stack Overflow.

But there is a way to to so my friend !
You want to provide the piece of code you think the error comes from, the things you have tried to solve this (so we don't just lose our time on this when you already have tried a solution) and ideally notify the thread with the solution you found if you solved the issue before other users could!

Have a great day, and I hope this may help you ask your future questions in a way that both benefits you and helps others understand and help you !

Answer (score 0):

You can use [markdown-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-pdf) and `fs` to do this.

First you set the `.md` file path and add an `output` path too:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const markdownpdf = require("markdown-pdf");

fs.createReadStream("./path-to-your-file/inputFile.md")
  .pipe(markdownpdf())
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./path-to-your-file/output.pdf"));
```